# showing $f_n$ converges uniformly using maximum and mininum values

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given the following sequence of functions,

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$$

I have found the points in $R$ where this sequence of functions is at its max and min values. I now need to use this to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly.

Max: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$, Min $-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

so I need to show that $$\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$$ or $$\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le b_n$$ where $\lim b_n=0$

So how can I show that this max and min approaches 0 or there is a $b_n$ that is greater than that and its $\lim=0$ to prove uniform convergence?

Comment: What is $f(x)$ in your case?

Comment: @Stefano I guess $f(x)=x$

Comment: I would guess $f(x) = 0$, which is the pointwise limit of $f_n$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oops you are right, $n$ should tend to infinity rather than 0

Comment: I have included my max and min value, do I need to use these as f(x) to prove that it is uniform?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a problem with convergence seems difficult, it is worth trying to go back to the definition.  In your case, you had better use the definition of **uniform** convergence; you seem to be hovering around definitions of convergence.

So we need to show that there is some function $f(x)$ and some integer-valued function $N(\epsilon)$ defined on $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $n>N(\epsilon)$ and all $x \in \Bbb R$, 
$$|f(x) - f_n(x)|<\epsilon$$

The first thing to notice is that if such an $f(x)$ exists, it will have to be $f(x)=0$ since for any given $x$, we can make $|f_n(x)|$ arbitrarily small by choosing $n$ large enough.

Now you can use your fact that $$\left| \frac{x}{1+nx^2} \right|  \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$ to say that for any given $\epsilon$, if $$N(\epsilon) = \frac1{4\epsilon^2}$$, then whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$,

$$|f(x) - f_n(x)| = |f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} <\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N(\epsilon)}} = \frac{1}
{2\frac{1}{2\epsilon}}=\epsilon \\
|f(x) - f_n(x)| <\epsilon
$$
so the definition of uniform convergence is met.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this just using the max value is that enough to prove convergence? do I need to use the min value too?

Comment: Since the definition talks about the absolute value, and the min is negative of the max, when you use the max value you are also using the min value.